# Why is a smooth scheme over a field reduced?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding of smoothness of scheme now. It is mentioned in many places that "a scheme smooth over a field is reduced" (which, of course, also enjoys other nice properties.). But now consider the situation that $X=\text{Spec }k[t]/(t^n) $ and $Y=\text{Spec }k$, where $k$ is a field. (Let's say it has characteristic 0.) Let $f:X\to Y$ be the natural map. Then, following the definition in Hartshorne's book,

1. $f$ is flat.
2. $\dim X=\dim Y+0$.
3. $\Omega_{X/Y}=0$

Thus, $f$ is smooth of relative dimension 0. But I think it should not be smooth. What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: How did you get 3? It is false.

Comment: @Mohan You are right. I was thinking the generator $dt$ module of differentials would vanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Omega_{X/Y}\neq 0$. In particular, the module of differentials $\Omega_{(k[t]/(t^n)/k)}$, which is the global sections of $\Omega_{X/Y}$, is a $k[t]/(t^n)$ module with generator $dt$ and relations generated by $nt^{n-1}dt=0$. So $dt$ is nonzero when $n>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are right. I stupidly treated the module of differentials as some "integral algebra".